# Isn't a bounty meant for the best answer or solution answer?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

Today, surfing over SO, I found a bit annoying situation for me. For details, refer to:

- [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554847/it-is-not-inserting-data-into-database)
- [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779578/loop-only-going-through-one-set-of-data)

You will most probably get what I am trying to ask.

Question one, the voting system and my common sense says that answer given by [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) is cleary better than the answer accepted for bounty...@YourCommonSense correctly called it a cheap way to get the repo points.

Now see the question 2, not so big difference, right? Please check the user who is asking the question.

**QUESTION**

the real question is, when someone announces a bounty over a question, there should be a quality check for answers which are awarded with bounty. If NO, Why?

My suggesstion is, there should be a quality check for answers that are awarded with bounty and bounty SHOULD GO TO BEST ANSWER not to the solution.

**Bounty**

Just saw th Bounty Definition over here on Meta

> A bounty is a way to get additional attention for a question by
>   offering some of your own reputation for great answers.

Comment: Just as the OP can accept any answer (and nobody can do anything about that) the user putting a bounty on a question can award it to whatever answer he/she likes.

Comment: Just to clarify your feature request a bit, who would arbitrate these quality checks?

Answer (score 7):

A user has to give up their own reputation points for bounty answers, so that user should be able to give the points to whoever they feel answered their specific question.

Another answer may be *better*, but that is what upvote reputation is for. Bounty is for the OP to get an answer that fixes their problem.

Comment: No, bounty is so that the person who posted the bounty gets an answer that addresses whatever they want addressed (people other than the OP can post bounties; if the OP posted the bounty, what you said was correct).